Normalization in cypress
I am running my cypress test and I am trying to assert this, but the test is failing because of the HTML Non-breaking spaces
cy.get('h3').should('contain.text', `Allocations for ${name}, ${role}`);

Here is the Error am getting in cypress

assertexpected <h3> to contain text Allocations for Me, Hello -IN-8464, Business Analyst, but the text was &nbsp;Allocations for me, Hello, A Business Analyst


Can you remove the non-breaking spaces from the input? This seems a case of garbage in, garbage out

Using match assertion allows the \s token to match non-breaking space as well as normal space.
For example
const nbsp = String.fromCharCode(160)   // nbsp is a single char
const actual = `${nbsp}String begins with a non-breaking space` // test string

cy.wrap(actual)
  .should('match', /\sString begins with a non-breaking space/)


The chai expression contain.text you used is not actually like cy.contains(), i.e it's not a partial match. Instead it's a synonym for have.text which is an exact match.
But if you use .should('contain', 'String begins with a non-breaking space') you get a partial match and the test will pass.
For the <h3> you need to extract the text before the assertion
cy.get('h3')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', 'Part of a string with a non-breaking space')

To handle nbsp inside the string, go with what Rory suggested
cy.get('h3')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => text.replace(/\u00A0/g, ' ')  // global replace
  .should('have.text', 'Full string with a non-breaking space')

